# Are there any HTTP/HTTPS interception tools like Fiddler for mac OS X?

Tags: debugging, http, macos, https, sniffing

I would like to know if there are any applications like fiddler but for mac OS X, as I need to debug some requests from web applications in Mac OS X. I used to do it with fiddler on Windows and would love to have this tool available on Mac as well.

Comment: Navigate to this URL in Google Chrome: chrome://net-internals/ You can use it to capture and dump a json file of all http traffic.

Comment: Pity that question is closed, as this is the first google result for "fiddler for mac".  Went for a search today, four years after, and settled for http://mitmproxy.org/

Comment: I agree. This question is definitely constructive and has some excellent recommendations. It hasn't solicited any "debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion" and doesn't seem likely to.

Comment: Other tips, since I too, came here expecting a living answer in SO style... Chrome Apps: Dev HTTP Client, Postman

Comment: I think its a good question and I'd like to see it open, but its off topic. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Try http://dutzi.github.io/tamper, it's a chrome extension that lets you inspect and modify HTTP requests

Comment: Try Do HTTP. You can directly install it from appstore. https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/do-http/id887133786?mt=12

Comment: Fireup Fiddler on nearby Windows machine and configure your MAC to proxy over Windows machine and voila! everything on your MAC will be seen on Windows :)

Comment: How is this not constructive?  Please be a little more relaxed in your post administration.  This is a very valid question.

Comment: I just discovered betwixt that seams very nice https://github.com/kdzwinel/betwixt

Comment: Gets an upvote just because it was closed

Comment: Now Fiddler is available for Mac as well. (Since October 2016)
https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: If you're looking for a native macOS. Checkout Proxyman https://proxyman.io

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There's the more general but perhaps not as helpful to you [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html).

One of the SO server sites might be better suited for your question. In fact, it's already been asked on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/42813/looking-for-http-debugging-proxy-for-mac-similar-to-fiddler-on-windows).

Comment: Thanks for the answer i've found in superUser that the monst similar it's Charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com/) but it's not free.
I will try with Wireshark.

Comment: Wireshark is a little advanced to install... is there an easier to get up and running Mac Fiddler?

Comment: @Leon: not that hasn't already been mentioned. You could go for the Firefox+LiveHTTPHeaders. HttpFox might also be useful. As for installing Wireshark, it's as easy as installing anything on a Mac: you just download the DMG from the Wireshark site, open it, and drag the app to your Applications folder.

Comment: Hey thanks I'll check out that LiveHTTP... I did install Wireshark as you said, but the configuration is the advanced part. I don't mess with terminal and can't find any of the specific folders they talk about on my Mac :(

Comment: Try http://dutzi.github.io/tamper, it's a chrome extension that lets you inspect and modify HTTP requests

Comment: Wireshark is probably one of my least favorite pieces of software. The UI is terribly un-intuitive. The docs look like they were made in 1994, and I have never once gotten it to do the things i needed.

Answer (score 24):

Charles is written in Java and runs on Macs.  It's not free though.

You can point your Mac at your Windows+Fiddler machine: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-NonWindows

And as of 2013, there's an Alpha download of Fiddler for the Mono Framework, which runs on Mac and Linux. Also, the very latest version of Fiddler can import .PCAP files captured from WireShark or other tools run on the Mac.

Comment: Thanks for writing Fiddler in the first place, Eric!

Comment: There is also a version of Fiddler for Mac OSX now http://fiddler.wikidot.com/mono

Comment: @EricLaw Can I monitor HTTP _S_ traffic when I use an external Windows+Fiddler machine?

Comment: @mg30rg: Sure. See step 11 here https://www.telerik.com/blogs/running-fiddler-in-virtualbox-on-mac

Comment: @EricLaw Nice one, thanks!

Comment: I am succesffully running fiddler in macOs, Linux as well Microsoft Thanks @EricLaw, Can you please help me understand this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56697981/network-sniffing-not-able-to-get-post-through-the-login-page-in-a-mobile-app-wh?noredirect=1#comment99960454_56697981

Comment: Java is every reason I need never to go near charles

Answer (score 13):

If you don't get any direct answer to this you could always run Fiddler on a windows machine and configure your browser on the Mac to use the windows machine as a proxy server.  Not very satisfactory and requires a second machine (although it could be virtual).

Comment: How do I configure Windows as proxy server?

Answer (score 13):

[HTTPScoop](http://www.tuffcode.com/) is awesome for inspecting the web traffic on your Mac. It's been incredibly helpful for me. I didn't think twice about the $15 price tag. There is a 14 day trial.

Comment: Dowsn't appear to work anymore, the download is corrupt, last update was almost 3 years ago and support doesn't respond.  Web site is up however...

Comment: Not good does not work with SSL

Comment: It seems to be shut down.

Answer (score 9):

Cocoa Packet Analyzer is similar to WireShark but with a much better interface.
http://www.tastycocoabytes.com/cpa/

Comment: and much easier install process! :)

Comment: That link appears to be dead; the whole domain is down, in fact. The Mac Store version of the app is incomplete (doesn't include the ability to capture). I found the [download here](http://download.cnet.com/Cocoa-Packet-Analyzer/3001-2085_4-146476.html) (version 1.3 at the time of this posting).

Answer (score 7):

> WebScarab is a framework for analysing applications that communicate using the HTTP and HTTPS protocols. It is written in Java, and is thus portable to many platforms. WebScarab has several modes of operation, implemented by a number of plugins. In its most common usage, WebScarab operates as an intercepting proxy, allowing the operator to review and modify requests created by the browser before they are sent to the server, and to review and modify responses returned from the server before they are received by the browser. WebScarab is able to intercept both HTTP and HTTPS communication. The operator can also review the conversations (requests and responses) that have passed through WebScarab.

http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project

Comment: Where can we find the install for Mac OS X? Corsaire's download page seems to be gone and, for me at least, the git links on dawes.za.net hangs.

Comment: Checkout the rewrite of WebScarab: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_WebScarab_NG_Project
Download from http://code.google.com/p/webscarab-ng/ then launch using java -jar WebScarab-ng-0.2.1.one-jar.jar

Answer (score 4):

The free [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) Firefox extension is pretty good. Allows you to view, filter and modify all requests.

Answer (score 3):

[Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) is an excellent Web Debugging Proxy for Windows, Mac OS and Linux. The full version is 50$ but it's well worth it.

Answer (score 2):

http://ditchnet.org/httpclient/

Comment: I've already have httpClient but it makes you build the requests instead of capturing the ones from the apps.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using Eclipse you might try http4e

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to add ServiceCapture to the list, for those who may come across this.

I've been using ServiceCapture for about 4 years and love it. It's not free, but it is a great tool and not very expensive. If you debug a lot of Flash or AJAX apps it is invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the possibilities are less, but FireBug (addon of FireFox) has some network analysis tools, too.