# Utility to view request/response headers during browsing session?

Tags: http, http-headers, utilities

I'm wondering if there are any utilities out there that will display the request/response headers sent/received by my web browser during a browsing session. Does anyone know of anything useful?

I'm familiar with the Modify Headers add-on for Firefox 4 and the HTTP Client utility for MacOSX but neither of these do quite what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) might help here - it captures all of the traffic, including headers, content, etc. It works on startup with IE or Chrome; Firefox needs to be configured to use it as a web proxy.

Comment: That looks useful but unfortunately I'm running Mac OS X Snow Leopard. Don't really want to set up a virtual machine, know of anything useful for mac?

Comment: Ah, sorry missed that.  Looks like some others have asked about this, and other suggestions include WireShark, or LiveHTTPHeaders for Firefox. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680381/are-there-any-http-https-interception-tools-like-fiddler-for-mac-os-x