# Need a handy tool to capture HTTP responses while I surf with my browser

Tags: http, google-chrome-devtools

For the stated purpose, I have been using Chrome's Developer Tools. I kinda enjoy using the suite as it allows me to easily capture and view HTTP responses (Under "Network" tool -> "Response" tab). Having that said, it lacks a feature that I need - the ability to search within a response document. To deal with this shortcoming, I would save the response document in a file and open it up in an editor, with which I perform my search. This solution is rather time-wasting. Is there a better solution available out there?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). It has great functionality for capturing all kind of web requests. Also it has the ability to search within a response document

Comment: Fiddler supports Windows only and I have a Mac :(

Comment: Check those replacements for MAC: (question on SO)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680381/are-there-any-http-https-interception-tools-like-fiddler-for-mac-os-x]

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to expose the requests that your browser chrome is managing, you can use a very powerful tool build in **Chrome**, you can access it from here:

```
chrome://net-internals/#events
```

It records DNS, Proxy, Cache, Extensions and all the Events, including URL_REQUEST, opened sockets, ...