# Safari HTTP monitor (like HttpFox) on mac

Tags: macos, http, safari, httpfox

I am looking for an HTTP traffic monitor/sniffer (something like Firefox's HTTPFox) for Safari, for debugging/development purposes.I am using OSX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn’t see a extension for Safari, but here are some tools for macOS you could use.

- [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html)
  You could look at Wiresahark (free, but a full blown packet sniffer). Not ideal for just HTTP.
- tcpdump ([nixCraft article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-monitor-sniff-apache-http-packets/))
  It’s command line (free).
- [Cocoa Packet Analyzer](http://www.tastycocoabytes.com/cpa/)
  It’s free, but it’s more like Wireshark.

Comment: Hi Rogier, I am using Mac system. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Subramanian, then you put that in your question. We don't have crystal balls here. Also, Wireshark has OS X builds.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best tools is [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) though it is currently only in [alpha for Mac & Linux systems](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/mono).
Another pretty good, though not free, tool for Mac OSX that I have found handy in the past is [Charles Web Debugging Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).
Also, consider exploring the debugging tools built into modern versions of Safari; they are very powerful an include a rich amount of network debug information.

(See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680381/are-there-any-http-https-interception-tools-like-fiddler-for-mac-os-x).)

Answer (score 0):

I have used [paros proxy](https://sourceforge.net/projects/paros/) to sniff all the http connection. I configure Safari to use the paros for all connection and inspect the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Captor](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/captor-http-analyzer/id1100708036) to capture HTTPS traffic on mac, you can capture safari traffic also. it is a native APP. you can download it from Apple Mac Store.