# Sniffing Live http headers for Flash chat

Tags: html, http, firefox, web

I am trying to check the http headers for flash,I tried firebug addon for flash, But its not showing for all.

For example , In below chat there is lots of chat communication going on but firebug cant catch it.What is the problem?

```
http://host10001.123flashchat.com/joinafrica/123flashchat.swf?init_host=host10001.123flashchat.com&init_port=21127&init_room=733&init_host_s=host10002.123flashchat.com&init_port_s=443&init_group=joinafrica
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) instead. This should catch all the traffic.

Comment: do u know anything for mac ??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680381/are-there-any-http-https-interception-tools-like-fiddler-for-mac-os-x